# Is there any difference between JME and J2ME?

Tags: java, java-me

I want to write a code for 3d game and I don't know that I need JME or J2ME,please help me! 
thanks.

Comment: I want to write a developing network 3d game,so I need what? java SE or java EE or...? thanks

Comment: You will be using Java SE on the client.  If there's a server component you'll likely use Java EE because that's what web-stack application platforms are built on.

Answer (score 10):

There seems to be some confusion in the answers here.
[JME](http://www.jmonkeyengine.com/) is short for jMonkey Engine framework which is "*a high-performance, 3D scenegraph based graphics API, written in Java*"

[Java ME (formerly J2ME)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Micro_Edition) is "*a Java platform designed for mobile devices and embedded systems*"

That is all.

Answer (score 5):

Back when Java 5 or 6 was released Sun officially declared the 1 in 1.x for Java redundant and only retained for program compatibility - externally the version is referred to as just x.  So the JVM which returns version 1.6.0 is called Java 6.

So there is no difference because Sun dropped the 2 at the same time that they changed to Java x instead of J2SE 1.x.  Simple reasoning works backward from Java 6 to Java 5, Java 4, Java 3, Java 2 and Java 1.  Having Java 3 - 6 referred to as J2SE n is confusing since in long form that means "Java n" is "Java 2 Standard Edition n".  Hence, J2xE were all changed to Java xE.

These days it's much easier to refer to Java 1 through Java 7 to indicate the Java version you are talking about.  The simple conclusion is, in hindsight which is always 20-20, Java 2 should never have been branded Java 1.2, it should have been 2.0.

Comment: Version 6 is the **product version**, while 1.6.0 is the **developer version**. http://java.sun.com/javase/6/webnotes/version-6.html

Comment: Version 1.5 was known as "J2SE 5.0". Version 1.6 is "Java SE 6". For Java EE, there was "Java EE 5". The leading "1." indicates binary compatibility. Presumably 1.9 will be followed by 1.10.

Comment: @Tom, yes I expect to see 1.10, 1.11, 1.12... too, with the "1." on the internal version number until Java is no more.  Although if Java 7 is any indication we may not ever make it to Java 10.

Answer (score 3):

No difference.  The "2" was dropped because the standard moved on.  Now it's Java SE for standard edition, Java EE for enterprise edition, and Java ME for mobile edition.

Comment: I have found this that JME is java Monkey engine and J2ME is java 2 mobile .is this correct?please help me thanks

Comment: @Johanna JME is Java Mobile Edition. Just the name changed for some crazy marketing reason. Make sure you get your info from the legitimate java.sun.com site.

Comment: that's ok  but I want to know that for making a network 3d game I should use which library?thanks

Comment: Try both the Java monkey engine and the Java mobile edition and see which one works better.

Comment: @Johanna: That JME can mean either Java ME or Java Monkey Engine is an unfortunate naming collision.  No matter what, these will happen.

Answer (score 2):

Sun renamed all their APIs recently. Java ME was J2ME, as Java SE was J2SE, Java EE was J2EE etc. So there's no difference.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Sun renamed things into Java SE, Java EE and Java ME (and not JSE, JEE, JME). So JME is something else.